# On Oracle, I cannot grant select privilege on v$Session to another user

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges

As the 'SYS' user, I can run the following command:

```
SYS> grant SELECT on V_$SESSION to "SOMEUSER" with GRANT OPTION;
```

Then, as that user, I can select from V$SESSION:

```
SOMEUSER> select * from V$SESSION;
 .....  Expected output .....
```

However, even though the user was given the GRANT option, I cannot GRANT that privilege to anyone else:

```
SOMEUSER> grant SELECT on V_$SESSION to "OTHERUSER" with GRANT OPTION;
grant select on V_$SESSION to "OTHERUSER"
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Strangely though, I can do this:

```
SOMEUSER> grant select on V$SESSION to "OTHERUSER";

Grant succeeded.
```

Why do I have to specify `V_$SESSION` when running as the SYS user, but when running as a normal user, I have to specify `V$SESSION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is `sys.v_$session`.  If you are logged in as `someuser`, `v_$session` would be resolved in the current schema, i.e. `someuser.v_$session`.  That object doesn't exist, hence the error

```
grant select on sys.v_$session ...
```

should work.

Comment: Very concise and clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`V_$SESSION` is a view, `V$SESSION` is a public synonym for that view.

```
select object_type, object_name from all_objects where object_name in ('V$SESSION', 'V_$SESSION')
```

| OBJECT_TYPE | OBJECT_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| VIEW | V_$SESSION |
| SYNONYM | V$SESSION |

```
select * from all_synonyms where synonym_name = 'V$SESSION'
```

| OWNER | SYNONYM_NAME | TABLE_OWNER | TABLE_NAME | DB_LINK | ORIGIN_CON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PUBLIC | V$SESSION | SYS | V_$SESSION | *null* | 1 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=eff8fe714200b1d62a7923344e4731e0)

When you do

```
grant select on V$SESSION to "OTHERUSER";
```

the synonym is apparently being expanded.

When you do

```
grant SELECT on V_$SESSION to "OTHERUSER" with GRANT OPTION;
```

you are trying to grant the privilege directly on the view - but on an object with that name *in your schema*, and no such object exists under `SOMEUSER`.

It would work if you did:

```
grant SELECT on SYS.V_$SESSION to "OTHERUSER" with GRANT OPTION;
```